# Not being able to write a data frame to a excel sheet

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel

This is the error message i am getting .Even on trying the code given by my tutor and online i tried fixing but ended up being not able to fix the problem

Comment: Install the `xlsxwriter` module.

Comment: (Also, please post your code and error message as text in the future.)

Comment: Sorry it was my first time in stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're requesting Pandas to use the `xlsxwriter` engine to write your XLSX file. The error says

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter'

To use the `xlsxwriter` engine, you'll need to install the [`xlsxwriter` module](https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/).

Usually, that's done with `pip install xlsxwriter`.